# parsing datetime using mvc and js

Tags: c#, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I have implemented jquery date picker, but I'm struggling with parsing datetime value. Scenario is following, user should select date using jquery datepicker, date should be on following format (`dd.MM.yy`), datetime value should be sent to the controller using ajax, and receive (for simplicity of these example) some dummy data over json.

I have following

```
Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/DateTime.cshtml

@model DateTime
@Html.TextBox("", Model.ToString("dd.MM.yy"),  new { @class = "date" })
```

Views/Home/
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyDate)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#pickDate').click(function () {
        var date = $('input[name="MyDate"]').val();    
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: { MyDate: date }, 
            url: '/Home/DateManipulation',
            success: function (result) { alert('Success');  },
            error: function () { alert("error"); }
        });    
    });
</script>

HomeController.cs
 [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult DateManipulation(string MyDate)
 {
    DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(MyDate, "dd.MM.yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);              
    var process = //omitting 
    return Json(process);
 }
```

And on the _Layout.cshtml I have on dom ready

```
 $('.date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd.MM.yy" });
```

> I'm not getting date on the controller, error is Invalid JSON
>   primitive: MyDate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your call to `/Home/DataManipulation/`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#pickDate').click(function () {
        var date = $('input[name="MyDate"]').val();    
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: { MyDate: date }, 
            url: '/Home/DateManipulation',
            success: function (result) { alert('Success');  },
            error: function () { alert("error"); }
        });    
    });
</script>
```

Try replacing `data: { MyDate: date }` with `data: JSON.stringify({ MyDate: date })`